# jquery toggleClass changing only once

Tags: jquery, html

I am making a slideshow with jQuery. I'm using jquery ui icons to be the play/pause button and so on. so I have this code:

```
$(function(){
    $(".controls").hide(); //Hide controls

    $(".slider").hover(function(){
        $(".controls").fadeIn(500);
    }, function(){
        $(".controls").fadeOut(500);
    }); // show controls on hover

    $(".play").click(function(){
        $(".slider").attr({'data-running' : 'true', 'data-paused' : 'false'});
        $(this).toggleClass("ui-icon-play ui-icon-pause play pause");
    });

    $(".pause").click(function(){
        $(".slider").attr({'data-running' : 'false', 'data-paused' : 'true'});
        $(this).toggleClass("ui-icon-play ui-icon-pause play pause");
    }); //Add play/pause functionality

});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="slider-wrap">
<div class="slider" data-running="false" data-paused="true">
    <img class="starter-img" src="http://images.freeimages.com/images/previews/e16/tree-1533498.jpg" />
    <a href="http://labs.blogs.com/.a/6a00d8341caed853ef016768796ee4970b-pi" role="img-data"></a>
    <a href="http://www.successconnections.com/articles/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/technology.jpg" role="img-data"></a>
    <span class="controls">
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-w prev control"></span>
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-play play control"></span>
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-e seek-for control">
    </span>
</div>
</div>
```

The first time I click on the play button, it switches the `data-running` attribute to `true`, the `data-paused` attribute to `false`, and it's own class to `ui-icon-pause pause`, as it should. But when I click it again, it's own class changes, but the `data-running` and the `data-paused` don't change. Why aren't the attribute changes being made? **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yak613/kbctqkbs/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$(".pause")` does not bind when you flip classes. It only finds the elements that are there at that moment in time. Either use event delegation or add logic inside the one click that handles both states.

Event delegation:

```
$(".controls").on("click", ".play", function(){
    $(".slider").attr({'data-running' : 'true', 'data-paused' : 'false'});
    $(this).toggleClass("ui-icon-play ui-icon-pause play pause");
});

$(".controls").on("click", ".pause", function(){
    $(".slider").attr({'data-running' : 'false', 'data-paused' : 'true'});
    $(this).toggleClass("ui-icon-play ui-icon-pause play pause");
}); //Add play/pause functionality
```

Better just do it in one since code is 95% the same

```
$(".controls").on("click", ".play", function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("ui-icon-play ui-icon-pause play pause");
    var isPaused = $(this).hasClass("pause");
    $(".slider").attr({'data-running' : !isPaused, 'data-paused' : isPaused});
});
```

Comment: Yeah, last time I checked I couldn't mark it. don't know why they do that.

Answer (score 0):

Your classes should be like this , as pause for play and vice versa

```
 $(".play").click(function(){
    $(".slider").attr({'data-running' : 'true', 'data-paused' : 'false'});
    $(this).toggleClass("ui-icon-play ui-icon-play play");
});

$(".pause").click(function(){
    $(".slider").attr({'data-running' : 'false', 'data-paused' : 'true'});
    $(this).toggleClass("ui-icon-play ui-icon-pause pause");
}); //Add play/pause functionality
```

Comment: No, `.play` is a play button, which means that it is paused. Either way, that wouldn't solve my problem.

Comment: ok if it is that so ..interchange the class with pause button and it would work

Answer (score 0):

I think I've ran into this issue.

> "The problem with jQuery’s Toggle is indeed as you pointed out that it
>   add’s an inline style to the element which does not get removed untill
>   the toggle is triggered again" -https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/issue-with-jquery-slidetoggle-display-none/

You need to reset the `.toggleClass` or use `.addClass` and `.removeClass` to achieve your effect.

If you don't want to create a reset function for your `.toggleClass` nor use `.addClass` / `.removeClass` you sometimes can getaway with wrapping with a `setTimeout` function. *ie. simple sample below:*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $(".wrap").toggleClass("fixed");

    setTimeout(function () {
      $('.wrap').toggleClass('shift')
    }, 20);

  });
});
```

[**CodePen of above in action**.](http://codepen.io/Anos/pen/bzkEB) *(< you are essentially resetting)*